# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.NullReferenceException:

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I am a beginner who is trying to make a 2D multiplayer game using Unity, and I found an error that is difficult to solve. I have tried to find a solution but still haven't found it. can you help me?
here is my code:

```cs
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviourPun, IPunObservable
{

    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public Animator animator;

    public PhotonView pv;
    private Vector3 smoothMove;

    private GameObject sceneCamera;
    public GameObject playerCamera;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            playerCamera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<GameObject>();
            //sceneCamera = playerCamera;

            sceneCamera.SetActive(false); // this is line 29
            playerCamera.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFO6G.png)
and this error message appears :

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerController.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:29)

Comment: your class isn't derived from Monobehaviour instead of it is derived from MonoBehaviourPun, I think it doesn't have Start Function you better check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sceneCamera` is never set and it's value is always `null` because you commented this line :

```cs
            //sceneCamera = playerCamera;
```

1. You can expose the `sceneCamera` field to the editor (by making it public for example)
2. You can find the main scene camera with `Camera.main`

But you should check if it's null before trying to disable it

```cs
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviourPun, IPunObservable
{

    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public Animator animator;

    public PhotonView pv;
    private Vector3 smoothMove;

    public GameObject sceneCamera;
    public GameObject playerCamera;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            playerCamera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<GameObject>();

            if (sceneCamera != null)
            {
                sceneCamera.SetActive(false);
            }
            if (playerCamera != null)
            {
                playerCamera.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```